# How to check if a zip fie is empty using perl

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl scipt that unzips the zip file and moves the content of zip file to a directory, however I want to skip the zip file which do not have any content in it. How can I filter these files. For unzipping the file I'm using

```
unzip_content = system("unzip -d <directory> -j -a <filepath>")
```

Could anyone suggest me anyway to check if it does not contain anything.

I tried with checking the filesize using `-s $filename` but later I got some files with filesize 22 byte but with no content in it.

Comment: That's not Perl code, that's Perl calling another program.

Comment: *die 'read error' unless $zipfile->read( 'sample.zip' ) == AZ_OK;*

Comment: `unzip -l file.zip` lists the contents of the archive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Archive::Zip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip) to achieve all of that inside of your Perl program without shelling out. You need to check if the archive contains anything, which can be done with the [`numberOfMembers` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#numberOfMembers()).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip qw/:ERROR_CODES/;

my @files = ...;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;

    # skip if archive cannot be opened
    next unless $zip->read($file) == AZ_OK;

    # skip if archive is empty
    next unless $zip->numberOfMembers;

    # extract everything
    $zip->extractTree({zipName => '<directory>'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other way to check the same thing is to calculate the MD5 hash of the file. MD5 hash of all empty zip files would be 76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c.
Helpful links:
[minimum size zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits)
[Digest::MD5](https://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::MD5  qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);

my $filedir = "/home/docs/file.zip";

open FILE, "$filedir";
my $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
$ctx->addfile (*FILE);
my $hash = $ctx->hexdigest;
close (FILE);

if($hash eq '76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c')
{
# empty file
}
```